# Using SSIS to insert records without inserting preexisting records

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a 290 million source data set and I get a daily download of 12 million records daily which contain data from the previous days downloads.  I am having trouble inserting the daily records into the source and excluding the records I already have.  Some of the records that are new may not be from the previous day they could be several days back so a date restriction wont work.  Please help.

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to define the specific problem and what you've already done to try to solve it.

Comment: What keys do you have to work with? Do you have the ability to add more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had this exact same issue basically in your Data flow of your SSIS you need to add a Lookup. Have it match the data your inserting to the new data based on the PK. then you can separate the data from here, choose Redirect Rows to no match output. This will make the green arrow contain all data that is no present.

Answer (score 0):

Lookup component using a key field and with the *no match* output, do an insert (you could also with the *match* output do an update; though 290million rows IS going to take **A WHILE**)...