# SSIS Lookup transformation to prevent duplicate entries

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to import some excel files to a sql server table using SSIS.
But problem is like when we consolidate data from all excel files to one then there is a chance that it may contain duplicate record.
to solve this I used Lookup transformation with "Lookup no match output" but no luck.
Can someone explain how to make it work with Lookup transform?

[image]

please refer attached image

Comment: What is the header of your file? What columns make a Row Unique?

Comment: This is a duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31061384/using-ssis-to-insert-records-without-inserting-preexisting-records/31061919#31061919

Comment: You'll need to show the details inside your lookup.   There's nothing wrong with what you have posted, so if it's not working you must doing something wrong in the implementation.   Also, the lookup can't be used to eliminate the dupes that are in the Excel file.   It can only be used to eliminate dupes that are already in your table.

Comment: You have to write a query that produces duplicates to do lookup on

Comment: @TabAlleman - you said lookup can not remove duplicates from excel (actually it's a .csv). are you sure?
in my case i want to prevent those records from csv file which are already in my target table. Will it work?

Comment: Yes, what I mean is that a lookup can be used to remove the rows in the csv that are already in your table.   However, if there are rows that duplicated in your csv (meaning you have the same row more than once in the same csv because you merged multiple files), then those duplicate rows will both pass through the lookup to your table.

Comment: Thanks @TabAlleman your answer did helped in understanding this lookup concept

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a sort task and check the 'Remove rows with duplicate sort values' box?